# C# Help - Check file exists and update SQL table with result

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add a section to a C# script that checks if a file exists and then updates a SQL table with a yes or no as a result of the check.  I've found how to check if a file exists, and how to update a SQL table but am having trouble joining the 2 together and integrating with the original script.

Is anyone able to help me out here?  I feel like it should be a simple thing to do, but I don't really know C# just muddling my way through it.

The final code that works:

if (File.Exists("D:\DPL\ALS\TempPDFStore\"+docnum+".pdf"))
                {

```
                // connect to database

                SqlConnection objSqlConnection=new SqlConnection("Server=123.456.789.0;Database=DB;User ID=sa;Password=pw;Trusted_Connection=False;");

                objSqlConnection.Open();  

                try  
                {  
                    string strINSERT = string.Format("UPDATE testwalog SET status = 'yes' WHERE docnum = '{0}'", docnum);
                    SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(strINSERT, objSqlConnection);
                    sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();  
                }

                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {

                }

                finally
                {
                    objSqlConnection.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Perhaps you can post the 2 parts that you have in code here and someone can help you in regards to refactoring this into one logical process or method...

Comment: post the two parts what you found here..

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer:) You should probably read a book, do a couple of tutorials, goto a course or etc. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (File.Exists("your file path"))
 {

    // connect to database

  SqlConnection objSqlConnection=new  SqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;uid=sa;pwd=;database=test");  

  objSqlConnection.Open();  

  try  
   {  
     SqlCommand sqlcom=new SqlCommand("your update sql statement here,objSqlConnection);  
     sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();  
   }

 catch (System.Exception ex)
   {

   }

finally
   {
     objSqlConnection.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: where in this example are you using the value in the file..? almost there. Your example should also utilize using Parameters i.e a Parameterized Query..

Comment: Thanks..I just give a simple example to user1944588...so maybe there are some problems..in most situations ..we can't put connect string there. aha.

Comment: I am talking about passing the @ParamValue,ValueFromFile in this situation ..but I am still waiting to see code sample from the OP ..

Comment: Thanks very much, worked well.  I was trying to pass a yes or no result to  the table, but just a yes works well.